# onClick странно работает

Tags: reactjs

В компоненте при нажатии на див нужно выводить другой блок (менять класс с display:none на block)

```
const clickClasses=['filtr_items']
const isCliked = () => {
    console.log('fwefwen')
    clickClasses.push('unhide')
    clickClasses.join(' ')
    
}

<div className="filtr_name"  onClick={isCliked}>Тип изделия <div className="znak" >{'>'}</div></div>
<div className={clickClasses.toString}>
```

Но почему то onClick срабатывает сам при загрузке сайта,при этом в консоли ничего нет,заранее спасибо

Comment: `clickClasses.join(' ')` - это что делает

Comment: @Igor все элементы массива преобразует в один в виде строки через пробел

Comment: И куда оно потом девается?

Comment: в этот же массив

Comment: Но это не точно?

Comment: Почему неточно,точно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133339/discussion-between-ivan-smirnoff-and-igor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось,что я дурачок и чтобы поменять что-либо в компоненте,нужно менять это через состояние:

```
import {useState } from "react";

const [buttonState,setButtonState] = useState(false)


const toggleClass = () => {
setButtonState(!buttonState);
 };

<div className="filtr_name"  onClick={toggleClass}>Тип изделия <div className="znak" >{'>'}</div></div>
<div className={buttonState ? 'filtr_items unhide': 'filtr_items'} >
```

Comment: В таком случае рекомендую закрыть данный вопрос, выбрав наиболее близкий к верному ответ (это может быть и Ваш ответ) :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете реализовать это немного по-другому, вместо того чтобы создавать объект, Вы можете просто объявить функцию:

```js
function Cliker(){
    console.log('fwefwen')
    clickClasses.push('unhide')
    clickClasses.join(' ')
}
```

И вызывать вот так: `onclick="Clicker()"`

**P.S** понимаю что это не совсем Ваш вопрос, но если не сможете разобраться с Вашим способом всегда можете вернутся к этому)

Comment: Извините,не работает